# Remove Javascript comments RegEx

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Hi I'm trying to remove all javascript comment (`//`) with in the HTML document. for example

```
<html>

<img src="http://example.com/img.jpg" />

<script>
//Some comments

gallery: {
      enabled: true,
      navigateByImgClick: true,
      preload: [0,1] // Will preload 0 - before current, and 1 after the current image
    },
</script>

</html>
```

Following is my regex code `[^(http?s:)|ftp]\/\/(.*)`. This is working. But I want to make sure, Is there any way to improve this code. ?

Comment: Place your js inside own files (.js) and minify :) ?

Comment: What do you want to improve ? does it fail for some reasons ? Isn't it  performant enough ? Also, I don't see the point... if that's important for you not to show the comments, you should really do this server-side, not client-side.

Comment: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/javascript-comment-removal-revisted/

Comment: That regex looks not only wrong for the task, but syntactically incorrect.

Comment: The fact that 50% of your regex is a special case for two scenarios gives it a really bad smell. What if the code had: `console.log("this is a string with two slashes //");` What if some non-URL, non-JavaScript part of your HTML had two slashes somewhere? As Mauno V. said, if you want to remove the comments from your JS, then minify it.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex says "match any character that isn't in `fhpts?:()`, followed by two literal slashes and anything to the ened of the line"

Normlly you'd want to do `(?<!http)(?<!https)(?<!ftp)\/\/.*`, however JavaScript doesn't support lookbehinds (much to everyone's disappointment) so consider doing this:

```
.replace(/\s\/\/.*/,"")
```

This will require comments to have a space before them (which they almost always do) - it's not perfect, but it's the best I can think of right now XD